# Android - redraw UI on back navigaation when using singelTop

Tags: android, user-interface

To avoid OnDestory() and OnCreate() beeing called all the time when navigating between my main activity and some sub activities, I have set the singleTop option in my manifest. Unfortunatly this causes that the UI in my main activity is gone when returning from a sub activity. Do I really need to redraw my UI manually?

I am still wondering how to handle these basic navigation features. Is it unusual to perform application initialization tasks (e.g. start services) in OnCreate() of the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something from your explanation I guess because the very basic point that you provided is not correct. When you launch another (sub) activity from your activity then your starting activity is not destroyed but it is stopped. So your onStart is called when you navigate back.
So maybe you can explain a little bit more the background of your requirements.

Comment: I am using the "android:parentActivityName" in my manifest to activate back navigation in my sub acticities. Unfortunatly this by default causes that my main activity will be recreated from scratch when returning (ondestroy + oncreate). To prevent this I used the singleTop attribute. But this now causes that my Main activity is not redrawn when returning.

So I am basically wondering how the correct impelementation of such a basic applications design looks like. :-/

Comment: Let's verify some basics. If you remove the singleTop flag and start an activity A from your main activity without specifying flags for the startActivity flag that activity A is added to your backstack. Your main activity is not destroyed but stopped and when you navigate back (back button or drawer) it is started again. If that is not the case then your system decided to destroy the stopped main activity which normally only happens if the system is low on memory or your main activity is still consuming too much power. So something is wrong in your main activity - simply speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your main activity so the system will not re-create it if you call it via Intent. You can also clear the stack and go back to your main activity by using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SubActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intentHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intentHome);
```

Comment: But when using singleTask flag I need to redraw my app manually,.. . Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry but singleTaks does not make sense in this case. It simply means that no separate instance will be created but has nothing to do with the backstack as the launched activity is added and not the launching. Also those flags that you specified apply to the launched activity (subactivity) which is not the issue here.